# About Photon Absorption

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, semiconductor-physics, quantum-optics

In QED, I learn that it is impossible to have first order perturbation in which an electron absorbs or emits an photon (initial particle: electron + photon, final particle: electron). This can be proved by taking into account the photon 4-monentum is light-like ($k^2$=0).

It also says that in constant external electrostatic field, this (meaning scattering of electron by the field) becomes possible because now the photon is virtual photon (so it doesn't have to fulfill $k^2$=0). My first question is, this virtual photon comes from the external field, right?

My second question is, in semiconductor, it is very often to have single photon absorption to promote electron from valence band to conduction band or with conduction bands or from traps to bands and vice versa. Based on what we discussed in the first paragraph, it should not be possible. Why it is possible in semiconductor (I guess this is not 2nd order perturbation)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In QED, I learn that it is impossible to have first order perturbation in which an electron absorbs or emits an photon (initial particle: electron + photon, final particle: electron). This can be proved by taking into account the photon 4-monentum is light-like (k^2=0).

A single free electron cannot absorb a photon because at the center of mass, the (Photon + electron) incoming has  the summed four vectors and an invariant mass , the outgoing is a single electron and at rest by construction, has the fixed electron mass=rest-energy, which is less than the incoming invariant mass: contradiction.

> It also says that in constant external electrostatic field, this (meaning scattering of electron by the field) becomes possible because now the photon is virtual photon (so it doesn't have to fulfill k2=0). My first question is, this virtual photon comes from the external field, right?

Yes, but the external field is coming from another real "particle" a nucleus, another electron, the lattice and energy and momentum can be balanced.

> My second question is, in semiconductor, it is very often to have single photon absorption to promote electron from valence band to conduction band or with conduction bands or from traps to bands and vice versa. Based on what we discussed in the first paragraph, it should not be possible. Why it is possible in semiconductor (I guess this is not 2nd order perturbation)?

It is possible because the lattice has an energy momentum vector that balances the conservation of momentum and energy. It is usual to ignore it and talk of free electrons, but they are not really free, they are in a continuum of bound states [in the lattice.](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Solids/band.html)